# On selected value from Dropdownlist update table in sql database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I put Dropdownlist inside my GridView1, and the dropdownlist has values 0 and 1. What I want is: depending on the selected value from dropDownlist to update the column [Status] whit that value in my sql database???

```
protected void SQL_Update(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e){

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Korisnik;Integrated Security=True";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE RegistracijaKorisnik SET Status = " + ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList2")).SelectedValue; ;
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();}
```

Comment: When you say 'inside' what do you mean? Inside the EditTemplate of the Status Column?

Comment: in item template  http://postimage.org/image/57losotad/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the DropDownList and you bind it whichever way:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" OnRowUpdating="SQL_Update">
  <asp:TemplateField> 
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="Btn" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField> 
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" /> 
    </EditItemTemplate> 
  </asp:TemplateField> 
</asp:GridView>
```

In your code behind, you should have an Updating event, specifically using `GridViewUpdateEventArgs e`

```
protected void SQL_Update(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   /*
     You'll have to find the control in the GridView, using FindControl, and cast it to a DropDownList  
     Using ddl.SelectedValue isn't going to work
   */
   string sql = "Update table set Status = " + ((DropDownList)Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddl")).SelectedValue 
   //Other SQL logic here

   //Commit the database changes, using whichever SQL driver you have.
}
```

Comment: ok. i write this. Now how to call SQL_Update? what else i need to write in DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged or in Page_load?

Comment: Edited my answer.  Notice that there is a 'OnRowUpdating' piece in the GridView.  The button has a Command Name 'Update' which should fire the appropriate event.  

There shouldn't need to be anything to write in SelectedIndexChanged or Page_Load, unless there are modifications that you need to make to the DropDownList before calling the update command.

Comment: I don't know where I do mistake, but don't update the table when i choose value from the dropdownlist. :/ and don't need me button only when i choose value from dropdownlist to update that value in the table (column Status).

Comment: I edit my post, can you tell where i make mistake in SQL_Update?

Comment: Also keep in mind that after you update the database, to show the changes, you're going to have to rebind the gridview, using the method you used to bind the gridview in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, and from the information you have given I think the solution would be to have an

```
<asp:TemplateField />
```

Column with the DropDownList in the the

```
<EditTemplate>
```

of this Column. You then need some kind of Button in the GridView which has

```
CommandName="Edit"
```

This will fire the editing event of the GridView which you use to identify the index of the row which is being edited and setting

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
```

Now within that row you will have the DropDownList with the value 0 and 1. You also need to have in your EditTemplate a Button which will save the changes with

```
CommandName="Update"
```

You then handle the grid's RowUpdating event to find the new value from the DropdownList when RowUpdating is fired, update the relevant row in the database with this new data and then set the GridView's EditIndex property back to '-1' to stop editing that row. You then want to rebind the data in the GridView to show the changes.

A small example could be something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="EditImageButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" ToolTip="Save" CommandName="Update"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% #Eval("Status")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditTemplate>
        <asp:DropdownList ID="List" runat="server" />
    <EdiTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = Session["domainData"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int index = GridView1.EditIndex;
    int key = Convert.ToInt32(GridView.DataKeys[index].Value);
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    DropdownList = row.FindControl("List") as DropDownList;

    // Save changes to database

    // GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    // Rebind grid data
}
```